# Expression meaning: "To strongly urge"

Tags: phrase-requests

My current plight is that our dog has gone missing! I am creating a poster, and am asking anyone who may be reading to provide any information they may have.

Essentially what I am trying to convey is "We plea that you inform us on anything you may know"; quick and simple.

I find myself irritated, knowing that an expression for this exists but I cannot remember it.

Comment: You might be looking for ***implore*** but that’s not really a word i’d put on a poster like that.

Comment: Yeah I've grasped that since writing this, although I appreciate your answer as 'implore' was exactly the word I was looking for. Thanks. :)

Comment: Lost pet posters that I have seen just say 'Please phone us if you have seen Spotty'.

Comment: whatever you decide upon ... offer a big reward!

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with "beg" in this context -- "We beg you to inform us of any clues you may have."

Answer (score 1):

Could you be thinking of "Beseech?"

From the OED:

> To beg earnestly for, entreat (a thing).

Comment: good ... but on a poster tacked to a telephone pole?